# Would switching access points drop a websocket connection?

Tags: websocket

My question says it all.  I am walking around a site with a websocket app that works on my phone and there are numerous wire less access points around the area.

Still though, I have a very hard time with maintaining a connection.  Is it possible that when I go from one area to another, switching access points (not wi fi networks) would cause my websocket connection to break.

If it does, is there a way to immediately detect this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the WebSocket library used in your app does not detect a dropped connection and retry the connection, then your app will be out of luck.  That's why any good WebSocket library must be able to recover from a broken connection.

You can detect an outage in two ways:  either wait for OS to tell you the underlying TCP connection is broken (which can be many minutes), or come up with a "are we still connected" protocol where you send something to the server every so often and require a response (if no response, you assume you are disconnected).